# Is any content slider like jQuery bxSlider present in angular?

Tags: angularjs, bower

I want to add content slider like jQuery bxslider. But the bxSlider is dependent upon the jQuery library. I have not added jQuery externally in my angular app. Does anyone have an idea is any bower component present for content slider, which is not externally dependent upon jQuery ?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is a carousel. You could use the [angular-carousel](http://blog.revolunet.com/angular-carousel/) for this purpose. There are much more examples of [other carousel utilities here](http://ngmodules.org/tags/carousel).